# How to run a script to execute to a node a specific folder

Tags: node.js, linux, sh, exec, shelljs

There are two or more projects on node js.

For example, the first project is located in the folder: "/project/one", inside one of the js functions we execute:

```
const projectTwoPath = "/project/two";
exec(`sh ${projectTwoPath}/projectRun.sh`, ...)
exec(`sh ./projectRun.sh`, {cwd: projectTwoPath }, ...)
```

`projectRun.sh` contains:

```
npx prisma migrate dev
pm2 start npm --name "project-two" -- run start
```

The script is executed, but for project One.
Question: how to run this script so that it is executed for project Two, being in "/project/one", so that it is executed for the node in "/project/two"? (Option can be from the Linux console, or can within node exec(or shelljs) example)

Answer (score 1):

In order to accomplish this, you will want to use a subshell such as `(cd ./two && sh ../one/command.sh)`. What this does is spawn a subshell, cd into the `project/two` directory then run the script in `project/one` while still in the context of `project/two`. Upon this being completed, the subshell will automatically terminate itself. Throughout this entire process, your main shell is still in the previous context.

Comment: Not really, I'm trying to run a command from project One in project Two so it applies to project two. Rather than just run a command to project One from another folder

Comment: @VanHemer I see, in that case you want to spawn a subshell and run everything within that. In the linux shell, it would look something like this `(cd ./two && sh ../one/command.sh)`. If this is what you are looking for, I will update my answer to go more in depth as to what this does.

Comment: yes, logically you understood correctly, that what I'm looking for

Comment: @VanHemer Alright, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok, i tried this logic, so running from node exec, but node.js trying to launch script from projectOne, it's changed only thing, from where to run script. But the logic is to make the script work for projectTwo. Maybe need to work around spawn or fork.

Comment: Hm, not sure how it would work with node exec. I've only tested this with the linux shell.